# What does "=>" mean in import in scala?

Tags: scala, import, symbols

I am new to scala. I am looking through some code and came up with a code that imports `com.infinite.usermanagement.controllers.{ SecurityService => BaseSecurityService }` package. I was wondering what does => sign means in an import.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As others have mentioned, it's an import rename. There is however one further feature that proves astoundingly-useful on occasion that I would like to highlight: If you "rename" to `_`, the symbol is no longer imported.

This is useful in a few cases. The simplest is that you'd like to do a wildcard import from two packages, but there's a name that's defined in both and you're only interested in one of them:

```
import java.io.{ File=>_, _ }
import somelibrary._
```

Now when you reference `File`, it will unambiguously use the `somelibrary.File` without having to fully-qualify it.

In that case, you could have also renamed `java.io.File` to another name to get it out of the way, but sometimes you really do not want a name visible at all. This is the case for packages that contain implicits. If you do not want a particular implicit conversion (e.g. if you'd rather have a compile error) then you have to delete its name completely:

```
import somelibrary.{RichFile => _, _}
// Files now won't become surprise RichFiles
```

Comment: why got 2 underscores separated by a comma?

Comment: These are two imports. The first underscore is an import-with-rename to `_` except it actually deletes the name rather than rename it. The second is a wildcard import. Scala does overload `_` rather a lot, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 16):

This line means you import the class `SecurityService` and rename it to `BaseSecurityService`. You can use this to prevent name conflicts, etc. You can use this class by using `BaseSecurityService` instead of the original class name.

A very common example is the following (to prevent mixing up Scala and Java classes):

```
import java.util.{Map => JMap, List => JList}
```